Difficulty Obtaining Bayesfactor in Baysian Correlation in R (correlationBF from BayesFactor)
I am relatively new to Bayesian Analyses and am currently working on computing a Bayesian correlation between two measures of affective polarization (val_pvv and ther_pvv) within my dataset (df_clean). The goal is to quantitatively demonstrate their high degree of similarity.
My approach has been to use the correlationBF function from the BayesFactor package as follows:
cor_pvv_ther_val <- correlationBF(df_clean$val_pvv, df_clean$ther_pvv)

This results in the following warning:
Warning message: In genhypergeo_series_pos(U = c((n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2), L = ((n +  : Series not converged.

Despite this warning, the describe_posterior function provides a summary for the posterior distribution, yet it does not include the Bayes Factor (BF):
Summary of Posterior Distribution

Parameter | Median |       95% CI |   pd |          ROPE | % in ROPE | BF |         Prior
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rho       |   0.92 | [0.90, 0.93] | 100% | [-0.05, 0.05] |        0% |    | Beta (1 +- 1)

As can also be seen here:
> extractBF(cor_pvv_ther_val)           bf error                     time        code Alt., r=1 NA     0 Wed Apr  3 16:54:41 2024 1f88c5878bf

Given the high median, I suspect the issue with the BF calculation might be related to the extreme correlation value, potentially leading to some issues with the computation of the BF. While the substantial correlation and the low probability of the null model are evident (and the other outputs are quite clear), obtaining the BF would be necessary to be consistent in my analysis reporting. I have the same issue when modifying the rscale argument (e.g., to wide or ultrawide).
I would be very happy about some further information on the warning and about some suggestions on how to solve the issue.
Thank you very much in advance!
